# MVC Forms Authentication allows passthrough

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization, forms-authentication, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a MVC 5 application with the [Authorize] attribute placed at the top of the class for my controller that I don't want unauthorized users to access.  I have the following in my settings in my Web.config file

```
<location path="">
  <system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
  </authorization>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Login" timeout="15" />
  </authentication>
</system.web>
</location>
```

When I run the application I am redirected to the Login page, however, if I know the name of the Controller/Action I want I can bypass the login page without entering any credentials, for example the same exact controller from above where I have the [Authorize] attribute placed at the class level.  This should not happen.  I realize this may have to do with my path="" but I am trying to deny all access until a user is logged in and I tried "*" and "~" but they didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

First, MVC5 does not use FormsAuthentication by default.  It uses ASP.NET Identity.  So setting your authentication format to "Forms" will cause you problems unless you are actually using Windows Forms.  In fact, you will probably find this in your web.config, which completely disables it:

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Second, Microsoft's official position is that you cannot secure MVC applications through web.config location configuration.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/03/23/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-4-app-and-the-new-allowanonymous-attribute.aspx

> You cannot use routing or web.config files to secure your MVC application. The only supported way to secure your MVC application is to apply the Authorize attribute to each controller and use the new  AllowAnonymous attribute on the login and register actions. Making security decisions based on the current area is a Very Bad Thing and will open your application to vulnerabilities.
>
> Web.config-based security should never be used in an MVC application. The reason for this is that multiple URLs can potentially hit a controller, and putting these checks in Web.config invariably misses something.

Comment: I read through this and found it helpful but it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: @user2146538 - No, it doesn't solve your problem because you can't do things the way you're trying to do them.

Comment: would you mind telling me how I can then.  This was the focus of the post.

Comment: @user2146538 - There isn't enough information in your question to suggest any alternatives.  You don't even seem to know what kind of authentication you're using... Without knowing what you're actually doing, we can't fix your problem.

Comment: What I was asking CAN be done, it is not recommended.  Clearly, you didn't read my question and instead tried to boost your reputation but providing a copy/paste answer from the link provided.  This isn't really all that much help Eric and CLEARLY I put "Forms" authentication in the post twice.